# Spring RESTFul: What's the best way to store audio files?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, storage

There is a RESTFul application in Spring.

There is a simple entity class. Each object of the entity class has an audio file that is associated with it.

Earlier, I made storage of images in the catalog on the server.

Now, I think about storage audio files in the database in a separate table.

What do you think:
What's the best way for storage of audio files - catalog or database? All audio files are small and about 50 KB. But the number of files can be about 1500-2000.

Comment: what is a catalog in here?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the audio files should be uploaded on a file server like Amazon S3. And the database table has their information to load when you need it.

The simplest example is here. You need to think about what to store in the table about each file.

TABLE_FILES

| filename | extension | mime_type | s3_url |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| audio1 | mp3 | audio/mpeg | https://.... |
| image1 | jpg | image/jpg | https://.... |

Happy Coding!